# How do i reduce the repeadly use of % operator for faster execution in C

Tags: c++

This is code   -

```
for (i = 1; i<=1000000 ; i++ ) {
      for ( j = 1; j<= 1000000; j++ ) {
         for ( k = 1; k<= 1000000; k++ ) {   
             if (i % j == k && j%k == 0) 
                  count++;
          }
      }
}
```

or is it better to reduce any % operation that goes upto million times in any programme ??

**edit-  i am sorry** ,
initialized by 0, let say i = 1 ok!

now, if i reduce the third loop as @darshan's answer then both the first
&& second loop can run upto N times

and also it calculating % , n*n times. ex- 2021 mod 2022 , then 2021 mod 2023..........and so on

so my question is- % modulus is twice (and maybe more) as heavy as compared to +, - so there's any other logic can be implemented here ?? which is alternate for this question. and gives the same answer as this logic will give..

Thank you so much for knowledgeable comments & help-

Question is:

> 3 integers (A,B,C) is considered to be special if it satisfies the
> following properties for a given integer N :
>
> ```
> A mod B=C
> B mod C=0
> 1≤A,B,C≤N
> ```

I'm so curious if there is any other smartest solution which can greatly reduces time complexity.

Comment: You could also rearrange the order of the innermost loops so that `j` increases by `k` at a time instead of `1` at a time. There's almost certainly some number-theoretic way to compute this count that's way faster than O(n^3) though so it may not make much difference.

Comment: Start the j loop at i and start the k loop at j.

Comment: This program will never stop executing. It is O(n^3) and n is too high. Read about time complexity. What is the original question?

Comment: Nobody is concerned about the obvious divide-by-zero happening in this code?

Comment: In fact expanding on my comment above we can further rearrange the loops--have `i` be the innermost loop, starting at `k` and incrementing by `j` each time. Then each execution of the inner loop we can unconditionally increment `count` and now to get the actual answer we just need to compute how long each loop is.

Comment: @risingStark There is a big difference between "never stop" and "take a long time." Well formed O(n^3) code will finish.

Comment: @paddy The divide by zero greatly reduces the execution time.

Comment: @sweenish I agree but you get the point. I dunno, just exaggerated subconciously maybe because I regularly practice competitive coding and just seeing O(n^3) gave me chills

Comment: @swee 10^18 loops takes about 10^9 seconds, or on the order of 30 years.  So no, there isn't a big difference; mean time to failure of almost any computer system is well under that (power outage, ram failure, whatever).

Comment: The first thing I’d do is comment out the innermost if completely and measure how long the program takes with no % operator calls at all.  That would give you an upper bound / best-case-scenario for performance (assuming it doesn’t allow the compiler to replace the entire program with the returning of a compile-time constant, of course)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner If you remove the `if`, a compiler will likely optimize all the loops into a single addition: https://godbolt.org/z/xPhcdfjeq.

Comment: @DanielLangr yes, that was what my parenthetical was about.  And a *really* smart optimizer could do that even with the if still present, since there is nothing in the program that couldn't be calculated at compile-time.

Comment: There is no real justification for the [embedded] tag here, or even C++17 for that matter.

Comment: This whole calculation can be done in advance. All the mainstream compilers seem to fail in optimizing the code well, even with the divide-by-zero bug fixed. But it can probably be translated to some manner of equation, then solved and placed as a magic number inside a `const`.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont  yes ,agreed. its not just about 10 or 100. what if we gives N as a 10s of millions. i must try to replace arithmatics everytime , mostly * / % in every solution to see how much it can be affect in time complexity.

Comment: @Arbaz : Perhaps but performance issues are not unique to either of these and it may just narrow your audience.  The point is there is nothing specific to embedded systems in this question.  Removing the loop-invariant expressions from evaluation in the loop is a fundamental principle.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont If I assume a single 4GHz core going nuts, I get 8 years. Since it would be able to execute 4*10^9 instructions per second. If my math is excluding something major, let me know. In any case, I was speaking generally about a general statement. It's not like I condone highly inefficient code.

Comment: @sweenish You have loop comparision, increment, etc; I'm assuming 1 iteration of a short loop every 10^-9 seconds, ie, 4-6 cycles per loop.  In practice, yes, you can go off and SIMD it or the like and improve throughput, but even then the factor is modest.  My point is that an inefficient algorithm with a large input size is equivalent to "forever", because mean time to hardware failure isn't all that long once you are talking about O(n^3) or worse algorithms.

Comment: I've voting to reopen because the example is self contained and there are definitive answers to simplifying it and improving the speed. It is/would be instructive to others because the [good] answers talk about refactoring the algorithm. (i.e.) Not all speedups are merely tweaks, but, sometimes a rewrite is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

A much Efficient code will be the below one , but I think it can be optimized much more.
First of all modulo (%) operator is quite expensive so try to avoid it on a large scale

```cpp
for(i = 0; i<=1000000 ; i++ ) 
     for( j = 0; j<= 1000000; j++ ) 
     {
          a = i%j;
          for( k = 0; k <= j; k++ )   
             if (a == k && j%k == 0) 
                  count++;
      }
```

We placed **a = i%j in second loop** because there is no need for it to be calculated every time k changes as it is **independent of k** and for the condition **j%k == 0 to be true , k should be <= j** hence change looping restrictions

Comment: Are you sure this *actually* makes the code faster? Hoisting `a` out of the inner loop is something I'd expect a compiler to be doing already. Case in point:  clang produces the exact same assembly: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/aE5jvEdW1.

Comment: yea , i got it. But although logic is same as calculation of % so It cannot reduce my time more than 0.00143 sec for 10^5. my exe time is 0.512 ~ and it takes same as 0.51111

Comment: @Arbaz "logic is same as calculation of %" Not really. This change really does remove a LOT of invocations to `%`. The reason the speed is the same is that this change was already being done for you by the compiler in your original code.

Comment: @Frank  Yes if you apply `-O3` the loop invariant will be optimised out.  That is not really a fair test of the fundamental time complexity of the code as written, but a test of the optimiser.  The fact that the optimiser may save save you from inefficient code is not to say that you should write wilfully inefficient code.

Comment: When expressed as above, it appears that the inner loop (`k`) can be eliminated entirely since nothing happens unless `a == k`.  The entire inner loop can be liminated by:  `if(j % (i%j) == 0 ) count++ ;`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code has undefined behavior due to division by zero: when `k` is zero then `j%k` is undefined, so I assume that all your loops should start with `1` and not `0`.

Usually the % and the / operators are much slower to execute than any other operation. It is possible to get rid of most invocations of the `%` operators in your code by several simple steps.

First, look at the `if` line:

```
if (i % j == k && j%k == 0)
```

The `i % j == k` has a very strict constrain over `k` which plays into your hands. It means that it is pointless to iterate `k` at all, since there is only one value of `k` that passes this condition.

```
for (i = 1; i<=1000000 ; i++ ) {
      for ( j = 1; j<= 1000000; j++ ) {
         k = i % j;
         // Constrain k to the range of the original loop.
         if (k <= 1000000 && k > 0 && j%k == 0)
                  count++;
      }
}
```

To get rid of "i % j" switch the loop. This change is possible since this code is affected only by which combinations of i,j are tested, not in the order in which they are introduced.

```
for ( j = 1; j<= 1000000; j++ ) {
      for (i = 1; i<=1000000 ; i++ ) {
         k = i % j;
         // Constrain k to the range of the original loop.
         if (k <= 1000000 && k > 0 && j%k == 0)
                  count++;
      }
}
```

Here it is easy to observe how `k` behaves, and use that in order to iterate on `k` directly without iterating on `i` and so getting rid of `i%j`. `k` iterates from `1` to `j-1` and then does it again and again. So all we have to do is to iterate over `k` directly in the loop of `i`. Note that `i%j` for `j == 1` is always `0`, and since `k==0` does not pass the condition of the `if` we can safely start with `j=2`, skipping `1`:

```
for ( j = 2; j<= 1000000; j++ ) {
      for (i = 1, k=1; i<=1000000 ; i++, k++ ) {
         if (k == j)
            k = 0;
         // Constrain k to the range of the original loop.
         if (k <= 1000000 && k > 0 && j%k == 0)
                  count++;
      }
}
```

This is still a waste to run `j%k` repeatedly for the same values of j,k (remember that `k` repeats several times in the inner loop). For example, for `j=3` the values of `i` and `k` go `{1,1}, {2,2}, {3,0}, {4,1}, {5,2},{6,0},..., {n*3, 0}, {n*3+1, 1}, {n*3+2, 2},...` (for any value of n in the range 0 < n <= (1000000-2)/3).

The values beyond n= floor((1000000-2)/3)== 333332 are tricky - let's have a look. For this value of n, `i=333332*3=999996` and k=0, so the last iteration of `{i,k}: {n*3,0},{n*3+1,1},{n*3+2, 2}` becomes {999996, 0}, {999997, 1}, {999998, 2}. You don't really need to iterate over all these values of `n` since each of them does exactly the same thing. All you have to do is to run it only once and multiply by the number of valid `n` values (which is 999996+1 in this case - adding 1 to include  n=0).

Since that did not cover all elements, you need to continue the remainder of the values: {999999, 0}, {1000000, 1}. Notice that unlike other iterations, there is no third value, since it would set `i` out-of-range.

```
for (int j = 2; j<= 1000000; j++ ) {
      if (j % 1000 == 0) std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << (double)j*100/1000000 << "%  \r" << std::flush;
      int innerCount = 0;
      for (int k=1; k<j ; k++ ) {
         if (j%k == 0)
             innerCount++;
      }
      int innerLoopRepeats = 1000000/j;
      count += innerCount * innerLoopRepeats;
      // complete the remainder:
      for (int k=1, i= j * innerLoopRepeats+1; i <= 1000000 ; k++, i++ ) {
         if (j%k == 0)
             count++;
      }

}
```

This is still extremely slow, but at least it completes in less than a day.
It is possible to have a further speed up by using an important property of divisibility.
Consider the first inner loop (it's almost the same for the second inner loop),
and notice that it does a lot of redundant work, and does it expensively.
Namely, if j%k==0, it means that k divides j and that there is pairK such that `pairK*k==j`.
It is trivial to calculate the pair of k: pairK=j/k.

Obviously, for k > sqrt(j) there is pairK < sqrt(j). This implies that any k > sqrt(j) can be extracted simply
by scanning all k < sqrt(j). This feature lets you loop over only a square root of all interesting values of `k`.
By searching only for `sqrt(j)` values gives a huge performance boost, and the whole program can finish in seconds.

Here is a view of the second inner loop:

```
      // complete the remainder:
      for (int k=1, i= j * innerLoopRepeats+1; i <= 1000000 && k*k <= j; k++, i++ ) {
         if (j%k == 0)
         {
             count++;
             int pairI = j * innerLoopRepeats + j / k;
             if (pairI != i && pairI <= 1000000) {
                    count++;
             }
         }
      }
```

The first inner loop has to go over a similar transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Just reorder indexation and calculate A based on constraints:

```cpp
void findAllSpecial(int N, void (*f)(int A, int B, int C))
{
    // 1 ≤ A,B,C ≤ N 
    for (int C = 1; C < N; ++C) {
        // B mod C = 0 
        for (int B = C; B < N; B += C) {
            // A mod B = C
            for (int A = C; A < N; A += B) {
                f(A, B, C);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No divisions not useless `if` just for loops and adding operations.

Answer (score -1):

Below is the obvious optimization:
The 3rd loop with 'k' is really not needed as there is already a many to One mapping from (I,j) -> k

What I understand from the code is that you want to calculate the number of (i,j) pairs such that the (i%j) is a factor of j. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: how did you get that i,j,k pair such that i%j=k and j%k=0